# How to access PHP object's individual value?

Tags: php

I am using the following wrapper for Email Hunter API...

```
require_once '/home/mysite/public_html/path/to/hunterio/vendor/autoload.php';

use Hiraya\Hunter;

$hunter = new Hunter('MY_API_KEY');
```

They key method is ...

```
$hunter->findEmailByCompany('microsoft.com', 'Bill Gates');
```

But I don't understand how to access and output the results - specifically, the "email" field.

I'm aware similar questions have been asked before, and I have examined many of the answers, but I cannot find a solution. `$hunter` is an object, right? They are pretty new to me.

Here are some of the things I have tried...

1.

```
echo $hunter->findEmailByCompany('microsoft.com', 'Bill Gates');
```

Outputs...

```
" {"data"}: { "first_name": "Bill", "last_name": "Gates", "email": "bill.gates@microsoft.com", "score": 91, "domain": "microsoft ....
```

2.

```
 var_dump($hunter);
```

Outputs...

```
object(Hiraya\Hunter)#25263 5) {["apiKey":protected] => string(40) ...
```

3.

```
$myobject = $hunter->findEmailByCompany('microsoft.com', 'Bill Gates');
print_r($myobject["data"]);
```

Outputs...

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'data' in...
```

Number 1. above gets closest, because it shows that property "email" is available, seemingly inside "data". I need to access "email."

**Edit**:

Slight misunderstanding from me... the library returns JSON.
Therefore, as the answers point out, I access an element using json_decode.

Comment: What does `var_dump($hunter->findEmailByCompany('microsoft.com', 'Bill Gates'));` output?

Comment: The lib returns json, so `json_decode` it: https://github.com/saintsweeto/hunterio/blob/c11b59dcf94a1443f38cca2a297a629da51fe53c/src/Client.php#L84

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is, what data type does `findEmailByCompany()` return?

If it's an object that's JSON-encoded as #1 (not clear, `__toString()` could be implemented in any way), then your email is in:

```
$hunter->findEmailByCompany('microsoft.com', 'Bill Gates')->email
```

or

```
$hunter->findEmailByCompany('microsoft.com', 'Bill Gates')->data->email
```

or

```
$hunter->findEmailByCompany('microsoft.com', 'Bill Gates')->data['email']
```

However, it's also possible that the object returned by `findEmailByCompany()` has an email field that's not public. Then you would have some getter method, for example `get('email')`.

**Edit:** It's also possible that the method just returns a JSON string. In that case it's something along the lines of:

```
json_decode($hunter->findEmailByCompany('microsoft.com', 'Bill Gates'))->data->email
```

Comment: 1. "Trying to get property of a non-object", 2. The same, but twice, 3. "Trying to get property of a non-object". I had tried similar. There's no documented `get('email')` that I know of.

Comment: Yeah your question doesn't provide enough information to give a definitive answer, I just gave some possibilities. You need to check the exact data type returned by `findEmailByCompany`. If it's an object, you need to check the exact properties of its class to see what you need to return. If it's not an object, it should be trivial, but you would need to know that.

Comment: Your json_decode suggestion did it. Should I amend my question? Ie. This was a JSON string rather than an object all along?

Comment: I think if you modify your question to include what apokryfos wrote in his comment, then the question will be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

As `findEmailByCompany()` returns JSON string (as mentioned in the [source code](https://github.com/saintsweeto/hunterio/blob/master/src/Hunter.php#L63)), you'll need to use:

```
$json = $hunter->findEmailByCompany('microsoft.com', 'Bill Gates');
$result = json_decode($json);
echo $result->data->email;
```